# sending user credentials on subsequent requests in web api basic authentication

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a RESTful mobile application using ASP.Net Web APIs. I am inclined to use Basic authentication. I have followed some SO articles here which gave me good start. I understood that "username:password" will be encoded and added to "Authorization: Basic " and sent it as header on subsequent http requests after authentication. But I have only one thing missing here is,
How do I send this "username:password" encoded string on every http request without using session or cookies
In Forms Authentication a cookie will be set. In membership User Principal will be set.
All http requests to web api comes from ajax and I need to set authorization header in beforeSend. But where do I get "username:password" encoded string from, on every page ajax request
Or I am wrong in thinking like this. how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep that string with you in some way, as otherwise it wont be available to you to send as below. You will have to take care of this part - *where do I get "username:password" encoded string from*.

The authorization method and a space as "Basic " is then put before encrypted string as below.

```
Authorization: Basic TheEncryptedUserNamePasswordGoesHere
```

Comment: yes, that is the question, my RESTful web apis are by definition stateless. I am sure using cookies or Session (I am not sure how these work in mobile environment) is not recommended. But on every request after login I need to have "user identity" information because REST design operations are self-contained, and each request must carry with it all the information that the server needs to know (i.e., user already got authenticated). So how am I supposed to achieve this?

Comment: These are two different thing - Stateless WebAPI and Stateless Mobile application. You may have Stateless WebAPI, but you can surely keep UserName / Password in memory (or a file or any other accessible locatoin) of your mobile application which can be used to be attached with each request.